# GEE: Finding number of classified pixels for entire image collection (Sentinel 2)

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, imagery, image-classification

I'm trying to calculate the number of pixels classified as ice for every image in my Sentinel 2 collection, but when I try to map my function over all the images, each feature in my test export has the same value (equal to the number of pixels classified as ice for the single image I initially run the function on). I would like to export the value of ice for each image and the date of that image. Here is part of my code:

```
//// 1. GEOMETRIES AND DATES ////
// initialize geometries, dates, and thresholds
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point(-160.06812, 62.91267)
//Map.centerObject(aoi, 12)

var cloud_thresh = 3
var image_num = 38

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED") // 2015-present

var s2_sel = s2
            .filterBounds(aoi)
            .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', cloud_thresh))


var n_images = s2_sel.size()
// print('number s2 images', n_images)
// print('all images', s2_sel)

//// 2. SELECT AND ANALYZE A SINGLE IMAGE ////
var s2_sel_list = s2_sel.toList(n_images)

// Select a single image (using numbers 0 through number of images total)
var single_image = ee.Image(s2_sel_list.get(image_num))
var single_water_image = ee.Image(s2_sel_list.get(8))

var all_image_num = ee.List.sequence(0, 111, 1)
print(all_image_num, 'image numbers')

print('example image date', single_image.date().format('MM-dd-YYYY'))

var getDate = function(image){
  var date = ee.Image(image).date().format('MM-dd-YYYY')
  return(date)
}

var all_dates = s2_sel_list.map(getDate)
print('all image date', all_dates)
var water_thresh = 0
var snow_thresh = 0.905

// create a function to get the area using reduce region
var percent_ice_all = function(list){
    var ndwi = single_water_image.normalizedDifference(['B3','B11'])
    var water = ndwi.gt(water_thresh).selfMask()////.clip(Grayling)
    var land = ndwi.lt(water_thresh)
                  .selfMask()  
                  .rename('land_area')
    var snow = single_image.select('B8').gt(1100)
                  .selfMask()
                  .updateMask(water)
  var total_area = water.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  maxPixels: 1e10,
  scale: 30
  })
  var area_ice = snow.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  maxPixels: 1e10
})


var area_ice1 = ee.Number(area_ice)
return(ee.Feature(null).set('area_ice1', area_ice1))
}

// map function over all images
var perc_ice = ee.FeatureCollection(all_dates.map(percent_ice_all))

print('test export', perc_ice.limit(3))

//// MAPPING SECTION ////
var s2_vis = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 5000}
Map.addLayer(single_image, s2_vis, 'example image')
Map.addLayer(water, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: '#0D00B6', opacity: 1}, 'water')
Map.addLayer(snow1, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: 'white', opacity: 1}, 'snow')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer your question by using your approach because it looks you're still learning GEE. When you said "I try to map my function over all the images" it is not true because you are using the wrong list **all_dates** instead **all_image_num**. This is a not orthodox way for doing this because it is more direct to map the original image collection s2 with corresponding filters (as in s2_sel).

My [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/21d9941c7654c33771e5ff47b1d3422a) with your approach is (where all areas with ice are calculated to better observe the corresponding variations):

```
//// 1. GEOMETRIES AND DATES ////
// initialize geometries, dates, and thresholds
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point(-160.06812, 62.91267);
Map.centerObject(aoi, 12);

var cloud_thresh = 3;
var image_num = 38;

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED") // 2015-present
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', cloud_thresh));

var all_image_num = ee.List.sequence(0, 110);
print(all_image_num, 'image numbers');

var water_thresh = 0;
var snow_thresh = 0.905;

var s2_list = s2.toList(s2.size());

// create a function to get the area using reduce region
var percent_ice_all = function(ele){
    
  var ndwi = ee.Image(ee.List(s2_list).get(ele)).normalizedDifference(['B3','B11'])
                                                .rename('ndwi');
  
  var water = ndwi.gt(water_thresh)
                  .selfMask()
                  .rename('water');
  
  var land = ndwi.lt(water_thresh)
                  .selfMask()  
                  .rename('land_area');
  
  var snow = ee.Image(ee.List(s2_list).get(ele)).select('B8').gt(1100)
                                                .selfMask()
                                                .updateMask(water)
                                                .rename('snow');

  var area_water = water.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    maxPixels: 1e10,
    scale: 30
  });
  
  var area_ice = snow.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e10
  }).get('snow');

  return area_ice //ee.Feature(null).set('area_ice', area_ice);

};

// map function over all images
var perc_ice = all_image_num.map(percent_ice_all);

print('test export', ee.List(perc_ice));

//// MAPPING SECTION ////
var s2_vis = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 5000};
//Map.addLayer(single_image, s2_vis, 'example image')
//Map.addLayer(water, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: '#0D00B6', opacity: 1}, 'water')
//Map.addLayer(snow1, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: 'white', opacity: 1}, 'snow')
```

After running it at GEE code editor, I got:

[image]

Now, values are varying but, I don't know if they are correct because you have masked areas and I would use **ee.PixelArea** method instead. Another aspect to consider is that the reference for the calculation of the snow cover from the **B8** band has not been provided.